# Simple pager php previous and next

Tags: php

I have read a bunch of tools and I copied some code but the code is half a mile! :)
I was wondering if its not possible to make a small one like this (you'll get my point)
Im just after a small pager with previous and next links to display the next page of results...

```
<?php

//pagination

$pagelimit = 5

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $pagelimit")
or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

echo $row['title'];

}

echo "<a href='index.php?page=" . $row[$id - $pagelimit] . "'> Previous</a></li>";
echo "<a href='index.php?page=" . $row[$id + $pagelimit] . "'> Next</a></li>";

?>
```

or something similar...that works! :)

Comment: What doesn't work with this code?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a suitable tutorial: [Paging Using PHP](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/paging-using-php.aspx)

In short, you should use `$_GET['page']` to add an offset in your mysql query, which will look something like this (you'll have to adjust it to make it fit your implementation, but it's the basic syntax)

```
SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $pagelimit
```

Comment: Hi, I have read that tutorial and since im a rookie I can't understand all that code. that's why I was aiming for a simple one

where/how do I use $GET['page'] and $offset?